# Предок жил(,) на природу надеясь(,) — с ветки ел и из озера пил

Tags: запятые

Нужны эти запятые в «Песенке о вещах» Боярского? Я думаю, что прям точно-преточно не нужны.

> Предок жил(,) на природу надеясь(,) — с ветки ел и из озера пил.

Comment: Леопольд: «_Я  думаю, что прям точно-преточно не нужны_». === А почему Вы так _думаете_ (если действительно думаете )?

Comment: Смотрите, Лео. _Предак жил на прирОду надеясь — с ветки ел и из озера пил_ — запятые не нужны, потому что суть в том, как именно он жил; _Предак жИл, на прирОду надеясь, — с ветки ел и из озера пил_ — обозначение каких-то действий одновременно с _жил_.

Comment: А почему _**предак**_ вместо орфографически правильного _предок_?

Comment: Лео, мой коммент можете воспринимать как ответ. Это по сути так.

Comment: А песню слушали? Как в ней-то писать?